# I am trying to make .docx file password protected using apache poi but it gives me below exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, passwords, apache-poi

org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream cannot be cast to class java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @588ab592; java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

> I am using java 1.8 with apache poi 3.17

Here is my code :

```
try {
      POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
      EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
      Encryptor encryptor = info.getEncryptor();
      encryptor.confirmPassword("abcdef");

      OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(filePathPass), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
      OutputStream os = encryptor.getDataStream(fs);
      opc.save(os);
      opc.close();

      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePathPass);
      fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
      fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this looks like you are using a mish-mash of incompatible jars - can you check your classpath and ensure that all the jar versions match? - this is far easier if you use a build tool like gradle or maven - which work out all the transitive dependencies and can be made to warn if they are incompatible

Comment: thank you. yes there is jar version mismatch in my project setup. I have tried running it on different system with same configuration and it works.